# How to answer this question?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

So, I have this question, and I am wondering how to answer it.

**question:**

bulb nr 1 blinks `every 6 seconds.`

bulb nr 2 blinks `every 7 seconds.`

bulb nr 3 blinks `every 28 seconds.`

Suddenly, they all blink at once. How long time until they blink at once again?

I am trying to figure out a formula to solve it, any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: find the least common multiple of $6,7$ and $28$.

Answer (score 2):

They will blink at once at $\alpha(84) : \alpha \in R, \alpha > 0$ since 84 is the least commom multiple of 6,7 and 28

Comment: There are many common multiples but there is something special about 84.

Comment: Sorry, the least common multiple! haha thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you know that every 28 seconds, bulb 2 and 3 will blink at the same time, you just have to find the LCM of 6 and 28 to figure out how often bulb 1 will blink bulb 3. Doing so gives you that every 84 seconds, bulb 1 will blink with bulb 3, and bulb 3 will always blink with bulb 2 since 28 is a multiple of 7.